# Chisel adding enable to a register that has a next field

Tags: scala, verilog, chisel

I have a floating point add chisel module that I want to use which has a few stages of pipelines. I want to make it stallable so that I can fit it into a pipeline which may not be able to consume the output data at any give time and therefore I would like the partially calculated adds to be stored in the module.

I was initially hoping that I could just add an enable signal and then just add it as another condition for updating the various registers, but unfortunately the module contains a lot of statements of the form Reg(next=xxx). I was curious to see what would happen if I just assigned the register to itself even though its input was already assigned through next=xxx so I made a test module and got some (in my opinion) strange results.

Here is the scala:

```
package Hello

import Chisel._

class Hello extends Module {
  val io = new Bundle { 
    val in = UInt(INPUT, 8)
    val en = Bool(INPUT)
    val out = UInt(OUTPUT, 8)
  }
  val test_reg = Reg(next = io.in)
  io.out := test_reg
  when (!io.en) {
    test_reg := test_reg
  }
}

object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  }
}
```

and here is the resulting verilog:

```
module Hello(input clk,
    input [7:0] io_in,
    input  io_en,
    output[7:0] io_out
);

  reg [7:0] test_reg;
  wire[7:0] T0;
  wire T1;

`ifndef SYNTHESIS
// synthesis translate_off
  integer initvar;
  initial begin
    #0.002;
    test_reg = {1{$random}};
  end
// synthesis translate_on
`endif

  assign io_out = test_reg;
  assign T0 = T1 ? test_reg : io_in;
  assign T1 = io_en ^ 1'h1;

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(T1) begin
      test_reg <= test_reg;
    end else begin
      test_reg <= io_in;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

What is curious to me is that the verilog appears to be nearly implementing the enable in two different ways. It uses T1 (!en) to mux between test_reg and io_in and labels the output T0. If T0 was fed unconditionally as an input to test_reg, I think this would have the desired functionality. Instead T0 is completely ignored and T1 is used in the if else block to select whether the register should update or not.

Ultimately, this example seems like it still works correctly but now I am a little scared to used in the more complex floating point unit if it behaves kind of unexpectedly in the simple case.

Is there a more elegant way to halt the pipeline of a floating point add module? I initially liked the above approach because I could just add a when(!en) block at the end that just writes the output of all state to its input. I think another approach would be to replace any instance of Reg(next=xxx) with Reg() and then a when(en) {reg := next} block that updates the register. Ultimately I am trying to learn Chisel so I am wondering what the cleanest way to do it is.

For reference, the floating point add module I am talking about is: https://github.com/zhemao/chisel-float/blob/master/src/main/scala/FPAdd.scala

Comment: Using Chisel.RegEnable(updateData, resetData, enable) instead of Reg could as well be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val test_reg = Reg(next = io.in)
io.out := test_reg
when (!io.en) {
  test_reg := test_reg
}
```

I believe this is bad coding practice - either use `Reg(next=...)` or specify the next value via `test_reg := ...` but don't mix both!  First, it's ambiguous to the reader which writer should take precedence (although the answer is "last writer wins").  Second, when the reader sees `Reg(next=...)` he is probably not expecting to see that writer overwritten elsewhere in the code.

Write it as:

```
val test_reg = Reg(io.in.clone())
when (io.en) { 
   test_reg := io.in
}
```

It will still generate some unused signals, but the code's intent is much clearer.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if(io_en) begin
    test_reg <= io_in;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used chisel but my guess would be that this:

```
when (io.en) {
  test_reg := io.in
}
```

would produce something like this:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if(io_en) begin
    test_reg <= io_in;
  end
end
```

Which I think is equivalent to what you have now, but much more readable.

Comment: The issue is that my example is trying to emulate what I would encounter trying to modify the floating point adder (code I didn't write). If I were writing it from scratch, I would do exactly that - update state elements based on enable being asserted. However, I am trying to modify the code while minimizing my chances of making an error so I want to rewrite the logic that is already there as little as possible. The original author (with no intent of having an enable) wrote things like val reg_manta = Reg(next = a_wrap.mantissa) which means I actually have to test for when io.en is not flase.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are trying to do, but by trying to hack this in by only adding lines of code you are just making it confusing for the next person who looks at the code.  That person will probably be you in the future and you will look at this and have no idea what it is supposed to do.  Better to comment out the old code and replace it with the new code.